# Getting to the parent of the current folder in SublimeText

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am using Terminal plugin http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/terminal to launch a terminal window. Its great. For a specific usecase, I want to do two additional things

1) Instead of opening the current directory in the terminal, I would like to open the directory's parent.
e.g.
 parent_dir
        child_dir  [context menu on this "Open Terminal Here"[will be renamed to something more appropriate] should open the terminal with parent_dir]

https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal/blob/master/Terminal.py#L110 has the code relevant for us
In sublime "self.window.folders()[0]" seems to return the current folder path. So I tried doing this.

```
os.path.dirname(self.window.folders()[0])
```

But its of no use

2) Once the parent dir is launched, I want to run a specific command "deploy course_correction" offered by a native python lib offered by a friend of mine.

My lack of know-how in python is obvious here. Please oblige if its a very minor thing that I couldnt figure out on my own.

Comment: Are you sure you want a terminal and not running a build system that will do your `deploy course_correction` and show the output?

Comment: @Vlakarados: for now we havent reached a place to use a build system yet.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I don't understand what you mean. Is opening parent directory of the file and running `deploy course_correction` from that directory is what you want?

Comment: exactly.I solved the first problem. This code seems to work.
'path = self.window.folders()[0]
os.path.dirname(path)'

My-MacBook-Pro:Parent_dir Me$


Now, I want 
My-MacBook-Pro:Parent_dir Me$ deploy course_correction

Comment: I will provide my suggestion to use build system as an answer

Comment: @Vlakarados: Sure, please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a build system for that purpose.

Let's say your project resides in `/var/project` and you are working with a file `myfile` in directory `/var/project/sys`.

So you create a new build system:

Tools -> Build system -> New build system...
Paste the following:

```
{
    "working_dir": "${file_path}/../",
    "shell_cmd": "deploy course_correction"
}
```

Hit save <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and save it to your sublime text user directory under the name `deploy_course_correction.sublime-build`.

This will make it show up in the build systems menu, and you should select it:

> Tools -> Build system -> deploy_course_correction

And having your file `/project/sys/myfile` opened and focused, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.

A build results panel will open with the output of your command.

I hope this is what you wanted.

You may tweak it not to be relative to the `sys/myfile` file if you wish.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! 
One additional q: How do I add a dynamic variable? deploy course_correction <dev_env> or <prod_env>

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that answer the question, upvoting means it's helpful, accepting means it answers the question :) Glad it helped!

Comment: What do you mean dynamic? I'm afraid it's only possible by making two different build systems

Comment: I accepted the answer. 
deploy course_correction <username> <pass> <env>
The last three variables are dynamic. I want to user to provide it in user-settings. I read from there and use here.

Comment: I suggest making a bash file that will be editable by every user, something like `#!/bin/bash deploy course_correction <username> <pass> <env>` and making build system to target that file instead

Comment: where do I store the bash file? I mean how does ST know where to pick the bash file from.

Comment: `working_dir` setting actually is equivalent to doing `cd /some/path` in command line, so it first changes the directory, then runs the `shell_cmd` command in that directory. If you want to run some file, then you'd better provide the full path to the file in `shell_cmd` like `/var/project/userexec.sh`